# How to identify who is calling my web services?

Tags: asp.net, .net

I have some webservices which are called by some clients and that includes through mobile and web.  I have no control on the clients code.
But, I need to identify who is calling my web services, via the IP address or something else.
Is there any way to identify that?

Answer (score 6):

A better approach to tracking this sort of thing is to introduce the notion of an API key. That way you know exactly who is using your service and you can track their usage etc.

On every call to your service the user would have to provide their key as a means of authorisation (**not authentication**). This sort of approach can generally help avoid misuse of an API, however, it can't eradicate it completely. At least with this approach if you do find malicious user it's as simple as disabling that particular API key.

Comment: This is a great solution, because clients can move between places and then get a new IP, so IP-tracking would get somewhere, but not as far as an API-key.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes I know that. but now I dont have any control over the clients.

Comment: @kandroid - if they don't present the API key, you won't serve them, or is that a problem ?

Comment: right now I have nothing at all, but at least if I can get the IP's would give me some ideas. Do you know how to identify the ip in this case?

Comment: @OndrejSvejdar thats a big problem. It is a running system and have to serve clients for the sake of business

Comment: @kandroid that's the point I am trying to make.... *gain* some control over your clients by introducing API keys. Tracking the IP address can be as useful as a needle in a haystack at times. Baring in mind IP addresses can be spoofed & users can sit behind routers/proxy servers trying to track the *real* IP address can be difficult.

Comment: @kandroid this answer is a great suggestion for the future, I've posted an answer that will be able to help in the immediate future.

Answer (score 1):

You should check your **IIS Logs**, these will list (if you have them turned on, default they are on) all the requests made to your server.

So search through the log for the URL of the service and check the logs around the time of requests you are having issues with and it will list the IP address.

Your logs can generally be found at: `C:\inetpub\logs\LogFiles`

**If the folder is empty then you are out of luck currently**, you will need to turn logging on in IIS and then you will be able to check them after a few hours and start seeing where requests are coming from.

---

**E.g a sample from a log.**

**2012-10-29 04:49:44** 129.35.250.132 GET /favicon.ico/sign-in returnUrl=%252ffavicon.ico 82 - **27.x.x.x** Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+rv:16.0)+Gecko/20100101+Firefox/16.0 200 0 0 514

---

So the first highlighted item is the date and time, and the second highlighted item is the IP address (redacted as it's a real log.)